# Partition an unpartitioned primary key index to become locally partitioned by primary key

Tags: oracle, index, partitioning

I tried:

```
alter index clave_primaria_de_b local;
```

and I read:

[ALTER INDEX](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_1008.htm#i2128532)

But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert a global index into a local index with an `ALTER INDEX` command. You need to drop the index and recreate it using the `LOCAL` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a table b with a Primary Key called clave_primaria_de_b, then I need to keep this relational structure but also I need to create a local index on b's primary key; so I have read I could:

```
alter table b disable cnstraint clave_primaria_de_b

create index indice_5 on b(a) local

alter table b enable constraint clave_primaria_de_b using index indice_5
```

I have a doubt could I include the using index clause when reenabling the
constraint?

Thank you for your help.

Also after posting I have a new doubt:
Imagine we are in a multiusers environment and we need to keep this table online for clients' queries so then if we want to disable the primary key but also keep new data been enforced by this primary key I would write the first line:

```
alter table b disable novalidate constraint clave_primaria_de_b
```

Because by default it is disable validate.